# Process each row of html table to call api and render the result back to a specific column

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
id|name
1 |name1
2 |name2
```

After clicking on the button I want to check with some api like
`/ispresent/{id}` for each row and add a column that contains `true` or `false` based on whether this id is present or not.

The problem here is after each api call, it immediately moves forward to the next line:

```
$('#tableid tbody tr').each(function() {
                    var dasid = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
                    $.get("/isPresent/"+id, function(data, status){
                        $(this).find("td").eq(5).html(data);
                    });
                });
```

I tried many things but I cannot get it to work. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `this` is bound to the function. Therefore the `this` in your inner function may not be the same as the outer function. To get around this one solution is to save the row in a separate variable, basically caching your `this`:

```
$('#tableid tbody tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).find("td");     // save the row
    var dasid = row.eq(1).html();
    $.get("/isPresent/"+id, function(data, status){
        row.eq(5).html(data);         // use saved row
    });
});
```

A bonus side-effect is your code is now a little smaller than before

Comment: I think `var row = $(this).find("td");` will save the `td` and not `tr`

Comment: @kewlashu It gets **all** `td` inside one `tr`, not **the** `td` thus it represents the row